# Python: can we get the value from the dict or object like the ts?

Tags: python

Isn't the python can get the object or dict like ts:

```js
let test = {a: 1, b: 2, c:3}
const {a, b} = test
```

The `a` and `b` are the key and the variable, it looks simple and not need two line code or `for...in` to get the `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
>>>
>>> d = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
>>>
>>> a, b, c = (lambda a, b, c: (a, b, c))(**d)
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
>>> c
3
>>>
```

Here is another example where we will only get few values.

```
>>> d2 = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4}
>>> a, b = (lambda a, b, **kwargs: (a, b))(**d2)
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
>>>
```

Comment: We need enum all keys in the lambda. if I have many keys and want to get some values by the keys, it's not a good idea.

Comment: In that case, what if you will use this statement, `a, b = (lambda a, b, **kwargs: (a, b))(**d)`.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you'll get is something along the lines of:

```
a, b = test['a'], test['b']  # dicts
a, b = test.a, test.b        # objects
```

Or, less repetitive if you have more:

```
a, b, c = (test[i] for i in ('a', 'b', 'c'))           # dicts
a, b, c = (getattr(test, i) for i in ('a', 'b', 'c'))  # objects
```

You could probably do funky things with using the `locals()` or `globals()` dicts and `.update`ing them with a set intersection for example, but you should always explicitly declare variables and not muck around with scope dicts.

Comment: Actually, the closest you'll get is `a, b = test.values()`, assuming you know the number of elements returned.

Comment: You can't always predict the order of dict values, so… nah.

Comment: `OrderedDict` if you're worried about that.

Comment: That's already so much declarative overhead that you may as well use one of these proposals here.

Comment: The questioneer didn't specify that the code should be small, neither do I think code has to be minimalistic. Of you're worried about one import statement in exchange for getting code to be closer to what the question was regarding, you're treading on light waters. Either your concern is number of rows, or your concern is "how do i get code that is similar to X", pick one.

Comment: Well, number of lines is primarily what OP seems to be worried about.

Comment: @Torxed, I think the `test.values()` is a list, not include the key, so we don't get the values with the keys. I also try this in the python, it returns an error: `ValueError: too many values to unpack`

Comment: `dict.values()` returns a dictionary view object (if I’m not mistaken). It functions similarly to a list but isn’t really a list since dictionaries are unordered. So in effect it’s like a hybrid set-list where the items are unordered and can have duplicates. _(from Python 3.7, dictionary order is now part of the language specification and can be relied upon.)_

Comment: @NCh Even if you can rely on the dict order staying the same, can you rely on the order the dict has been constructed in?! In the Javascript example, the order of the object doesn't matter. There's no equivalent in Python that makes the same guarantees.

Answer (score 1):

Just use two lines.  Anything else which works in one line is too clever, too hard to understand, and too easy to break in the future:

```
test = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c':3}
a = test['a']
b = test['b']
```